# Schedule an email to be sent in the future on Outlook

Tags: outlook, future, schedule

Outlook currently has a flag in Followup -

> Flag for Recipients

which allows to send a future reminder for followup to the recipient.

Although it sends it out as an email at the time when we are setting up this. I am looking for the ability to schedule to send this email in the future instead of at that time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DeferredDeliveryTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862081.aspx) property of the MailItem class which allows to set a Date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

The message goes to the outbox folder and stay there until the correct time to send it.

Comment: Is this to be used inside a vbscript or something?

Comment: Anywhere. The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications and programming languages.